# Obtener tag data con un lector NFC ACR1255U-J1

Tags: sdk, nfc

me veo en la situación de pedir su ayuda, estoy intentando leer el tag data con un lector NFC ACR1255U-J1, el cual tiene interfaz bluetooth y USB, el problema es que no he encontrado forma obtener la información.

Programas ocupados:
NFC21 Reader
Goto Tags
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]